# Another way of saying "accompanied by family members"?

Tags: british-english

I'm writing a sign-up form for an event. The form has a checkbox, where people can indicate if they are bringing family members.

Currently I have the field labeled:

> Accompanied by family members

Is this the appropriate way of saying this? Will it be clear to all readers? Or is there another expression I can use?

Comment: That seems clear to me. What might be unclear about it?

Comment: I don't know, it's what i think should be there. But i posted the question because i wasn't sure.

Comment: Family members is what immediately comes to my mind.

Comment: Would it in fact make any difference if someone brought, say, their girlfriend or boyfriend (who wouldn't ordinarily be classed as a "family member")? Assuming not, why not just label your checkbox **Guests**?

Comment: I believe you need to come up with a definition of family or shall I say restrict it. Your family can include people you've never met, like distant cousins.

Comment: I'm fine with the term 'family', it will do for my context . I was more concerned about the "accompanied by" part of it :P

Comment: Looks clear to me (BrEng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatical, clear, and I can't come up with a better suggestion.

Comment: as there are no other suggestions i'll accept this, thank you for taking away my doubts :)